Calcuating Fluctuations in (Thermodynamic) Temperature in Microcanonical Ensemble
The definition of (Thermodynamic) Temperature is indeed possible in microcanonical ensemble through the Gibb's Entropy as shown in this work (1). In this scenario, the temperature, essentially a statistical average, can be calculated using the formula,
\begin{equation}
T^{-1} = \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial E}\right)_{N,V}
\end{equation}
It can be precisely shown that this value corresponds to the thermodynamic temperature, as it follows the laws of thermodynamics, as shown in this article (1).
In the microcanonical ensemble, the temperature is not a state variable, hence one can expect a significant fluctuations in the temperature of the system. Is it possible to exactly calculate the fluctuations in Temperature, $\left(\Delta T \right)^2$, in the microcanonical ensemble? If yes, what is the dissipation parameter that would be associated to the fluctuation in Temperature, as it should lead to a form of fluctuation-dissipation theorem?
Analogous framework in Canonical ensemble
To offer an analogy, consider Canonical ensemble in which we calculate thermodynamic internal energy, $U$ through the average energy of the system $\left< E \right>$. Likewise, the fluctuations in energy $\left( \Delta E \right)^2$ is also calculated and shown to be related to the constant volume specific heat $C_v$ of the system.
$$
U = \left< E \right> \\
\Delta E^2 \propto C_v
$$
The last relationship provides the fluctuation-dissipation relationship in Canonical ensemble, wherein the energy fluctuations are related to heat dissipation in the system.
Refs:
(1) https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.05713.pdf
